# Missing buttons in settings after update to 2.5 beta

Tags: database, installation

After updating my dev install to 2.5 beta, I seem to be missing the action buttons for each tool category in the settings page, see attached image.

Anyone else experienced this?[image: There should be a red-ish GO button below these checkboxes]

This applies to all 5 categories ("update asset indexes", "clear caches" etc)

I tried to re-install the app folder (by completely replacing, not merging) but with no luck, so I'm beginning to think that this all comes down to some database issue...

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce this on a fresh install with either the latest Chrome or Safari.

Comment: I experienced this problem too with the menus plugin, I found the culprit in this file (line 5): craft/plugins/menus/templates/settings.html

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it was a badly written menu plugin, overriding styling of DOM elements outside of its own view scope. Sure it's related to Kyles suggestion above.