# Missing buttons after upgrading site to 2.5

Tags: admin, updates

Same issue as found here - but no resolution: [Missing buttons in settings after update to 2.5 beta](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/missing-buttons-in-settings-after-update-to-2-5-beta)

All of the orange buttons in the CP are missing but the code is there for the css and if I select a checkmark and unselect it then press return the functions still run.

The only thing I can think that may have triggered this is there was a license discrepancy while I ran the upgrade, but I can't recreate it on a new install.

It's missing on every single browser across multiple computers.

Comment: What browser/version are you seeing that on?  Do you have any Craft plugins installed that might be interfering?

Comment: I'm seeing it on Chrome - latest version, Safari also up to date. I even tested it on Microsoft Edge on my PC, same result.

Comment: Any Craft plugins installed?

Comment: Yep, even with them disabled same issue.

Comment: Ended up solving it just by setting up a new 2.5 craft environment and putting in my template and database, etc. Strange issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and resolved by fixing my Redactor configs. If you have a misconfigured file or a formatting error it causes problems related to rendering later in the page, likely related to Redactor throwing a javascript error.

Comment: My redactor configs are default and unmodified. Also not seeing any javascript or any errors of any kind.